# Starting parallel thread from main and waiting for result

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to start parallel thread that performs some job and after that wake up the main thread. My code is:

```
            class TokenThread extends Thread implements Runnable {

                public String local_token = null;

                private Object monitor = null;

              public TokenThread(Object monitor) {

                    this.monitor = monitor;

                }

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        local_token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, mEmail, SCOPE);

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {

                    }

// think that this thread must wait for main thread end

// his synchronized (monitor) block but it doesn't work 
                    synchronized (monitor) { 

                        monitor.notify();

                    }

                }

            } // END: class TokenThread


                // Creation of the monitor
                Object monitor = new Object();

                // New thread creation
                TokenThread getTokenThread = new TokenThread(monitor);

                try {

                    synchronized (monitor) { // Try to block object

                        getTokenThread.run();

                        monitor.wait(); // may wait(10000) for emergency

                    }


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {


                }

// Reciving a result from paralel thread object
                token = getTokenThread.local_token;
```

Problem is getTokenThread end it's run function before main thread make wait call on the monitor object. As result - main thread go sleep after getTokenThread end and no one can wake up it.

PS. This code working inside Asynk task and not trying to block UI

Comment: to start the thread, call `getTokenThread.start()`, not `run()`. And consider not blocking UI thread at all as it is extremely discouraged practice.

Comment: Did you tried Async Task for this. http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html ?

Comment: This work inside Asynk Task that need one more thread for HTTP connection. Problem to stop HTTP connection. By using disconnect() method I cannot immediately terminate HTTP connection. That still trying to connect 5-20 second before will throw IO Exception. Idea was make new thread and destroy it to kill inside thread HTTP connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you are doing (not blocking the gui thread etc.) then you can use the `Thread#join().`

## Example:

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        t.join();
        System.out.println("Thread is done!");
```